# How to break up data into good sized parts

Tags: math, hash, cryptography

I'm writing a multi-length-output hash function, but I've hit as stumbling block: how can i break up input data in such a way that the program will not have to deal with extremely long lists or run too many loops for the given data?

a = input length in bytes, a>=0
b = output length in nibbles, b>0

minimal padding is done to the data before running the actual hash, so the input length is basically the same as the post-padded length.
data is broken up into n sized pieces and expanded into a list

can anyone come up with a f(a) or f(a,b)?
if you need any more information just ask

Comment: So you want to break the data into pieces and you want to know how big they should be? And you don't want them to be too big and you don't want too many of them? Why not just pick a size you like?

Comment: i would use 512 bits or something, but the point is that i want the size of the indexes to be somewhat random (not pseudo-random, but just strange)

Comment: The size of the *indexes*? If you mean the number of pieces, then just use a constant block size and the varying length of messages will take care of that for you.

Comment: Are you using existing (public) hash functions to hash?